# How to show the scale number between 1-23

Tags: c#, database, int

I would like to show the number scale from 1-23. for now, I have data like the image below,

[image]

If the number equal to 1 = it will have a total 40, and I want to add scale number, if the number didn't have any data it will return default 0. How can I add that scale number?

```
  public List<NumberModel> GetHourTime(Number model)

    {
        var result = new List<NumberModel>();

    int[] values = new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23};

    var hours = this.Context.XNumbers).Where(x => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Code))).Select(x => x);

    result = hours.ToList().ToNumberModels().OrderBy(x => x.Hour)
         .GroupBy(x => x.Hour)
         .Select(x => new XNumber
         {
             Total = x.Sum(item => item.Total),
             Hour = x.Key 
    }).AsEnumerable().Take(30).ToList();

    return result;

     }
```

the expected result will be like this

```
1=40,
2=0,
3=23,
4=0,
5=0,
6=12,
7=0
........
```

and so on... until 23

Here is NumberModel class

```
 public class NumberModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public int Hour { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your code has syntax errors. Please also provide sample implementation of `XNumbers` and `Number ` class, as well as the code that calls the `GetHourTime()` method.

Comment: i successfully get the result, but it didnt show the scale 1-23, its only show like in database

Comment: You never need to create an array like your `values`. Look up the syntax of a "for" loop and use one.

Comment: can u give me an example? @iakobski

Comment: Sure, I'll have to put it in an answer for formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alarm bells should be ringing the moment you write a list of consecutive numbers as part of your program. Get the computer to do it for you. A simple `for` loop will do it.

I'm not clear on your data model, but once you've got a list of `NumberModel` you can output them in the format you want like this:

```
var data = new List<NumberModel>
{
    // Sample data
    new NumberModel{Hour=1,Total=40},
    new NumberModel{Hour=3,Total=23},
    new NumberModel{Hour=6,Total=12}
};
for (int i=1; i<=23; ++i)
{
    Console.Write($"{i}=");
    Console.WriteLine (data.Any(x => x.Hour==i)
        ? data.First(x => x.Hour==i).Total
        : 0);
}
```

Output:

```
1=40
2=0
3=23
4=0
5=0
6=12
7=0
8=0
...
```

Comment: im still configure how can i apply in LINQ of my code

Comment: As @[Corentin Pane] said right at the beginning, no-one can help with the answer to that without knowing about `model` and `XNumbers` and `GetHourTime()` etc.